# How to disable auto-indentation on newline in js2-mode?

Tags: emacs, js2-mode

I'm editing React `.jsx` files, and I don't want to indent on newline, how to disable it?

Comment: Which version of Emacs are you using?

Comment: In that case it's probably `electric-indent-mode`, not `js2-mode`, that is automatically indenting on newline. Try turning that off with `M-x` or `(electric-indent-mode -1)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`M-x electric-indent-local-mode` should do it if you're using Emacs-24.4.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically set this for all js2 buffers, but leave all other buffers alone?

Comment: The answer I gave only works on the current buffer.  So you can add it to your `js2-mode-hook`, as in: `(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook (lambda () (electric-indent-local-mode -1)))`

Answer (score 0):

What seems to work in Emacs 25.1.1 is setting `electric-layout-mode` to `-1`. 
So In `js2-mode-hook` add:

`(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook (lambda () (electric-layout-mode -1)))`